# How to read standard output from running process?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way to read standard output/error from any, GUI and non-GUI, already running process? I know about `NSTask` + `NSPipe` + `NSFileHandle`, but I want to connect to instead of run process myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach to the running process with gdb and redirect stdout and stderr to files. Check the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin) for details.