# Python: interacting with STDIN/OUT of a running process in *nix

Tags: python, unix, stdout, stdin

Is there any way of attaching a console's STDIN/STDOUT to an already running process?

**Use Case:**

I have a python script which runs another python script on the command line using `popen`.

Let's say `foo.py` runs `popen` to run `python bar.py`.

Then `bar.py` blocks on input. I can get the PID of `python bar.py`. Is there any way to attach a new console to the running python instance in order to be able to work interactively with it? This is specifically useful because I want to run `pdb` inside of `bar.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way. **But** you can modify the way you start `bar.py` in order to be prepared to take over stdin and stdout.

A simple method would be to just create named pipes and supply these as stdin/stdout in the `Popen` call. You may then connect to these pipes from you shell (`exec <pipe1 >pipe2`) and interact. This has the disadvantage that you must connect to the pipes to see what the process is doing. While you can work around that by using `tee` on a log file, depending on the terminal capability demands of `bar.py` this kind of interaction may not be the greatest pleasure.

A better way could be to incorporate a terminal multiplexer like [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) into you process tree. These tools can create a virtual terminal in which the application is run. You may then at any time attach and detach any other terminal to this terminal buffer. In your specific case, `foo.py` would run `screen` or `tmux`, which will run `python bar.py` in a complete (VT100) terminal emulation. Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: This sounds promising - I can get input/output working using `Popen` with named pipes, but I'm not sure how to use `exec`. I set up two named pipes using `os.mkfifo('/tmp/testout')` and `os.mkfifo('/tmp/testin')`, then running `Popen(cmd, stdout=open('/tmp/testout', 'a'), stdin=open('/tmp/testin', 'r'))`. I tried `exec > /tmp/testin < /tmp/testout`, but it doesn't look like it's doing anything

Comment: Using `screen` worked! What a beautiful solution - thanks! I'd still be interested to know how to use exec, if you're so inclined

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect `stdin` or `stdout` for a running process.  You can, however, add code to your caller -- `foo.py` -- that will read from `foo.py`'s `stdin` and send it to `bar.py`'s `stdout`, and vice-versa.

In this model, `foo.py` would connect `bar.py`'s `stdin` and `stdout` to pipes and would be responsible for shuttling data between those pipes and the real `stdin`/`stdout`.

Comment: FYI apparently it is possible to redirect stdin and stdout for a running process in some circumstances: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin (But this doesn't give me interactivity)

Comment: I think, after looking at your link, that the answer is still "no".  You can do a lot of things if you're willing to attach `gdb` to your process, but outside of your development environment they're not very practical.