# Separate STDOUT noise from ncurses

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal, ncurses

I am trying to run an `ncurses` GUI application on an ARM board. I am running it using the serial console `ttyAMA0` port. But when I run the ncurses program, the other processes running in the background will print debug messages i.e qDebub, qWarning into `STDOUT` i.e on the GUI layout and hence results in noise. I think the problem is because all the processes are using the same console device.

So is there is a command line  or programmatic solution for this problem so that I could not see the other process' `STDOUT` on my `ncurses` GUI ?

**P.S: I have tried GNU `screen` and [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593764/829316) solution and they work fine. But I want alternative solution for this**

Comment: Are the messages coming from program you started in the background or were they started by the system?

Comment: It is from the upper layer basically from `qt`