# How to see the current running Linux processes output^

Tags: linux, process, terminal, output, verbose

I have several Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) processes running on my computer. If I start one of them, I can see the verbose of it on my terminal. I have an other process that start a dozen of those processes so that they run in background. However, I would like to watch the output of one of these processes to see if the output is still ok and there are no error message. I know I could send everything into a log message, however, this would just use too much disk space. So, is there a way to "catch" the output of a running process in Linux using it's process Id?

Comment: So you don't have enough disk capacity to capture all the output, but you'd like to pick a process and start seeing it's output?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a lot of disk space. The problem is that I don't like to open and close the text file (in which some people propose to send the output in this file) all the time to get the most refreshed data. I would prefer to "catch" the process and get it's verbose when I need it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use redirection like

```
yourprogram arg1 arg2 > yourprog.out
```

or probably even (to redirect both stderr & stdout and run in the background)

```
yourprogram arg1 arg2 > yourprog.out 2>&1 &
```

In a different terminal, do

```
tail -f yourprog.out
```

<sup>With the `-f` option, the `tail` command will notice when the file is growing and will display its newest lines</sup>

But I can't see portable way to redirect after. Maybe `screen`, `batch`, `at`, `cron` might help you. Or opening the `/proc/1234/fd/1` ...

BTW, I am surprised you don't have enough temporary disk space for your output...

And I do like running `M-x shell` under emacs, and running my programm there.

Comment: Thanks, so I understand that to get the most recent data, I would have to run each time the command: tail -f yourprog.out ? It's not really a real time output as what we see when the program runs in the terminal.

Comment: No, try `tail -f yourprog.out` it will show you more output when file `yourprog.out` is growing, because some other program (e.g. `yourprogram`) is filling it...

Comment: Ok... but it's not real time. I must run the command (tail -f yourprog.out) to get the most updated text in the file... I want to see the verbose output of the process as when I run my program in the terminal.

Comment: tail -f output is updated every second by default, if the -s option won't let you go below that (and you need to), you can always write your own :-)

Comment: Ok, I must say, tail -f does the same "effect". The only problem now is to manage the size of the file that is growing with time. Any cue on this? How could I remove the first line after 30 days?

Comment: I have a php process running a websocket and some variables inside, but I can't stop it right now to 'echo/print_r'. Is there a way to capture those variables 'on the fly'?

Answer (score 5):

You can attach *gdb* to your running process and redirect stdout/err or both to some log file whenever you feel like looking at the output (**make sure the files exist before redirecting**):

```
gdb attach PID
  (gdb) p dup2(open("/tmp/mylogfile-stdout", 0), 1)
  (gdb) p dup2(open("/tmp/mylogfile-stderr", 0), 2)
  (gdb) detach
  (gdb) quit
```

When you want them to go back to being silent just do:

```
gdb attach PID
  (gdb) p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 1)
  (gdb) p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 2)
  (gdb) detach
  (gdb) quit
```

The 'detach' part is important, otherwise you will kill the process you're attached to when gdb exits. For more details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin).

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do is to check `fd` folder in `/proc/<PID>/fd`

in my case I have a python running on the system with a different terminal

I can see its logs by :

***1. Get Process ID***

```bash
ps -aux | grep python
```

[image]

***2. CD into /proc/504951/fd and view all/needed files***

```bash
cd /proc/504951/fd && tail -f *
```

[image]