# Preventing background process from writing to console

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux's bash, I know how to start a long running process and send it to the background.

For example `run.sh`, then press `Control+Z`, then type `bg 1`

Sometime I would like to continue do other work, but this background process keep printing to my `Putty` console -  which is annoying.

I know I can start the `run.sh &> /tmp/run.sh.log` thus pumping all output to `/tmp/run.sh.log` but sometime I just forgot to do so.

How do I stop that background process from printing to my console?

Comment: You wrote the answer: `script &> /to/somewhere`. Don't forget that, you may get logs printed to your `stdout`.

Comment: Assume I forget to do so, what is my alternative other then killing the process and start again?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have started the process already and want to stop it from printing to `stdout`, while still keeping it running, you may use:

```
stty tostop
```

When you give `stty` the `tostop` argument it stops the background processes that try to write to `stdout`

To enable the process to write again you may use `fg`.

Original source can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/972968/why-does-a-background-process-started-in-bash-print-stdout-to-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Control+Z is stopping your job (like pausing it) that's why you don't see the output. fg 1 makes it to reasume
To suppress all messages redirect everything to /dev/null

`./your_script.sh 2>&1 &`