# Create new STDOUT or STDERR log when size hit 20MB size?

Tags: tomcat, stdout, stderr, rollover, procrun

I am using Tomcat 8 to run application in Window 10 (Run as window service).

I would like to confirm how should I avoid the STDOUT or STDERR log file to be too big by any of two approach below:

Create new STDOUT or STDERR log when size hit 20MB size?
Is there any way to achieve on any approach above?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **you can't**.

While theoretically [Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (the executable, which launches Tomcat as a Window service) could regularly redirect the standard output and error streams to a new file (using techniques like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593724/11748454)), in practice it doesn't: the redirection of the standard streams is performed only once during startup.

There are some hints in the source code that a time-based rotation feature was considered in Procrun (cf. [github](https://github.com/apache/commons-daemon/blob/604ac139fa90ad83d6e14f2bac513784fe505f60/src/native/windows/apps/prunsrv/prunsrv.c#L269)), but it was never implemented. You might add a feature request to the [project's JIRA](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/issue-tracking.html).

The best solution available today is **don't send your logs to `stdout/stderr`**. All proper logging frameworks implement some sort of rotating logfiles.

In Tomcat's case you just need to:

1. Disable the `ConsoleHandler` in the [`logging.properties`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/conf/logging.properties) file by replacing the `.handlers` line with:

   ```
   .handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
   ```

   The remaining handler writes to `catalina.<date>.log` and is rotated daily.
2. Redirect all output sent to `System.out/System.err` to the handler above, by setting [`swallowOutput="true"`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) in `context.xml`:

   ```xml
   <Context swallowOutput="true">
       ...
   </Context>
   ```
3. If your applications use a different logging framework from `java.util.logging` (e.g. Log4j, Logback) configure the logging system to log to a file instead of the console.